Lake reconfiguration suitability using ArcGIS Pro
I need to score floodplain lakes based on how easily/feasibly they could be reconfigured or if they need to be removed to:

Maintain lake fishing access as a whole through the whole valley (ie. if a lake is removed, that fishing access has to be made up for elsewhere) and
Increase the amount of floodplain space the river has (the main goal).

I've thought about using the suitability analysis tool and throwing in: slope of downstream berm, surface area, perimeter, and percentage of floodplain obscured by the lake-with slope weighted higher- to find the biggest problem lakes, which would be helpful. BUT ultimately, what I'm determining is their suitability based on what CHANGES can be made, for example: if the size and shape were to reconfigured (along with depth, which we can't analyze because we don't have bathy) can we increase the floodplain amount to at least 60% available on a cross-section while also maintaining at least a 10 acre lake and if we do, does the reconfiguration (lengthening or filling) create a safe/feasible downstream berm based on slope (not too high/not beyond dam parameters)? Not sure how to use the Suitability Analysis tool to analyze hypotheticals without some serious modeling and additional data that I don't have. For reference, I only have the current DEM, a current REM, the lake polygons, the valley floor/floodplain extents, and the river centerline.
Is there someway to do this that I haven't considered?

Just throwing this into the mix of ideas you might have. RivEX can extract the inlets/outlet of a lake with this tool. They could be used as starting points to trace u/s or compute catchment areas which may be of interest to your research?
